# UIPopoverController - supporting both iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

My client requires that a legacy UIPopoverViewController with an embedded UINavigationController is supported on both iOS 7 and 8.  I'm having a lot of difficulty with this overall and I'm wondering if anyone else has had more success in this area.

I'm using a combination of the following practices:

- `setPopoverContentSize:`, which seems only to be supported on iOS 7.  I'm specifying this only on iOS 7 devices.
- `preferredContentSize` property of `presentingViewController.presentedViewController`, which seems only to be supported on iOS 8.

On iOS 7 specifically, some wonky resizing seems to occur as a result of the navigation controller pushing a view.  I think this size might be inferred by the XIB itself `:(`...

Is there possibly something I am missing in terms of iOS 7 support?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in another post from this morning, I was setting the above params at the wrong time -- moving them to viewDidLayoutSubviews resulted in a reasonable solution to the problem.  Layout still isn't perfectly consistent between iOS 7 & 8, but it's now close enough.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to present a popover that has a navcontroller embedded in it. As far as I can tell, it works exactly the same on iOS 5-8. The code is called from a button in the NavBar, so I haven’t had to worry about setting it up at the wrong time. I set the POPOVER_WIDTH and POPOVER_HEIGHT in #defines because I have several popovers and I want them all to be the same.

```
if (self.myPopoverController == nil) {

        SettingsTableViewController *svc = [[SettingsTableViewController alloc]
                                            initInManagedObjectContext:self.mObjContext
                                            withScoreKeeper:self.scoreKeeper
                                            withWordList:self.wordList];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:svc];
        navController.delegate = self;
        UIPopoverController *popover =  [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
        popover.delegate = self;
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(POPOVER_WIDTH, POPOVER_HEIGHT);
        self.myPopoverController = popover;
        [svc setPopover:popover];
   // }
}
[self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:buttonPressed permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```